# Можно ли загружать файлы с пк на бота телеграм, где посредник хероку?

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

На хероку слишком маленькая база, всего 5мб и 100мб. Я хотел бы так сказать брать файлы с пк, не загружая на хостинг, которые далее будут использованы в боте.

То есть получается, что бот будет брать файлы не с сервера хероку, а с пк и дальше передавать их в бота, который в свою очередь будет присылать это пользователю телеграма.

Comment: никак не получится сделать

Comment: Какие файлы нужно использовать? Если это медиафайлы, то достаточно хранить их айди в базе данных и по ним отправлять